# How to get cookies from GET API using HTTPClient and extract value from them

Tags: httpclient, rest

I am using httpclient to automate rest api Get calls and in same I am getting cookies that contains csrf token that I need to login into my project , but I am not able to find out the way how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

just need to print `closeableHttpResponse` , it will give you all responses and then get the cookie value like this

```
String value = closeableHttpResponse.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")[0].getValue();
```